# How to read int data from mixed CSV file in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, parsing, int

I have a mixed CSV file that at the beginning has two columns with string data, and after about 100 rows the file has float values in more than two columns. The problem is when I read the file using csv.reader, it reads all the data as a string and I can't do any manipulation on the float data. In the end, I will get rid of the string data, because the CSV file will be transferred to DB. 
Any ideas about how to do that?

Example of how the file looks like:

```
aaa,bbb
aa,bbbb
aaa,dddd
eee,rrr
...
12.2,15.345,13.566,14.66,100.5
13,545,245.452,-0.422
```

Comment: u can use `pandas.read_csv` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: You can just pass each string element of each row to `float()` to convert them into that type.

Comment: Why do you say "int data" in the title of your question, but mention float values in the body? It's unclear what you want to do and you have no code showing what you have or have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how you'll have 100 lines to discard:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as r:
    for i in range(100):
        next(r)
    for row in csv.reader(r, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC):
        ...
```

If you don't know in advance:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as r:
    z = itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: line.count(',') == 1 or line.count('"') > 0, r)
    for row in csv.reader(z, delimiter=',',  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC):
        ...
```

Code untested, but the gist should be clear: iterate on `r` until you consume the stuff you don't want, and only then pass the file object to the `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas` you can use the `skiprows` parameter to skip rows from the top of the csv. Assuming the first 4 rows have the string type rows, you can specify `skiprows=4`. Here's how to do it:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: test_string = """aaa,bbb
   ...: aa,bbbb
   ...: aaa,dddd
   ...: eee,rrr
   ...: num1,num2,num3,num4,num5
   ...: 12.2,15.345,13.566,14.66,100.5
   ...: 13,545,245.452,-0.422"""

In [3]: with open("test.csv", 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write(test_string)
   ...:

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skiprows=4)

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]:
   num1     num2     num3    num4   num5
0  12.2   15.345   13.566  14.660  100.5
1  13.0  545.000  245.452  -0.422    NaN
```

Comment: Pandas is nice. :)